# Is this a bug of require of Perl 5.8.8?

Tags: perl, require

Code as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print 1;
{
require shift;                                                                        
}
```

It turns out that when I run `./script script`,two `1`s are printed.

So my script file is actually loaded twice? Is this a bug or not??

According to the document:

> "require" demands that a library file be included if it hasn’t already
>   been included.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`require` only skips loading a file if it was previously loaded with `require`, `use`, or `do`, not for something loaded as the primary script.

See: [%INC](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%25INC)

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not a bug. Your script prints 1, then requires the name of the first argument, in this case you've supplied the name 'script' which runs your script again printing the second 1.

See [Require](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html);

`The file must return true as the last statement to indicate successful execution of any initialization code, so it's customary to end such a file with 1; unless you're sure it'll return true otherwise. But it's better just to put the 1; , in case you add more statements.`

Also you should see some error, such as `Null filename used at script line 5`

Comment: Isn't `require` supposed to do nothing if the file is already included?? `"require" demands that a library file be included if it hasn’t already been included.`

Comment: Modules return 1 at the end so that require works as you intend. If you read the Require docs I linked to: `The file must return true as the last statement to indicate successful execution of any initialization code, so it's customary to end such a file with 1; unless you're sure it'll return true otherwise. But it's better just to put the 1; , in case you add more statements.`

Comment: I tried adding `1` to the end,still the same,say, got two `1`s.

Comment: Pleaes actually read all of the Require docs I linked to. You are requiring a perl script rather than a module/library. Perls Require doesn't work (inline) like #include does for C. You've not stated what you are actually trying to do here?

Comment: Do you mean `require` only checks for `require bare_word`,not for `require "bare_word"`?? I'm trying to understand why `require` include my `script` twice,which is different from its document ..

Comment: See also http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=890189 for other problems in this area

Comment: I doubt why your answer is so long, and doesn't seems to hit the nail on the head.

Comment: Because I'm rigorous for the **correct** answer,but I won't hesitate if I found a correct one!

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code i get:

```
$ ./script script
Null filename used at script line 5.
Compilation failed in require at ./script line 5.
11$
```

So I can't reproduce your result... ;)

You're making a false assumption: the fact that your script is called 'script' has nothing to do with it being `use`d, `require`d on `do`ne... the `require` statement is the first time something is required.